# How to handle nested react-router routes when serving bundle.js with express?

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, react-redux, react-router

I am using webpack-dev-server at the dev side for my react-redux app and for production, I am bundling all JS files into one bundle.js . Now I created a basic express app and serving the bundle.js and index.html using the following code.

**server.js**

```
app.use(express.static('app'));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/app/" + "index.html");
});
```

The following is my React component for routes:

```
return (
        <div>
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Header/>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
                    <Route path="/signup" component={Signup}/>
                    <Route path="/forgetPassword" component={ForgetPassword}/>
                    <Route path="/wallets" component={Wallets}/>
                    <Route path="/orders" component={Orders}/>
                    <Route path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
                    <Route path="/markets" component={MarketsList}/>
                    <Route path="/market/:marketPair" component={MarketDetail}/>
                    <Route path="/resetPassword/:token" component={ResetPassword}/>
                </div>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
```

The problem is for the nested routes. The single-level routes like login and signup work fine. But the routes like /market/:marketPair and /resetPassword/:token give the following error at the browser console:

```
bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

When clicked bundle.js , it shows my index.html file.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 2 potential issues:

- Path for `bundle.js` is relative
- Express doesn't know about the routes

I'm not sure how you create your index.html file and if it's processed by webpack or not, but:

If `bundle.js` is loaded correctly from the top-level routes `/login`, `/signup`, etc, but not by routes like `/resetPassword/:token`, it's probably because the webpage tries to load `/resetPassword/bundle.js`, instead of `/bundle.js`.

If that's the case, check the path of `bundle.js` resource in your index.html.

Comment: Yes. You're right! Its looking for resetPassword/bundle.js and that's where it crashes. But how to fix that?

Comment: I do not know how you generate the index.html file, but let's say that you have this:

`<script src="bundle.js"></script>`

You instead want

`<script src="/bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes. Adding a slash helped. I got it. Thanks Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely an issue with the `webpack config`. Make sure that the file is bundled correctly, and you have an output folder with all the correct files that your `HTML div` is expecting. Running the webpack may start the bundle if its not configured in your `package.json`

Check your config file for the file name, the id that your div expects and other mismatch in names